# How to handle two domains and forward everything (non www and www) to one Heroku app?

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, dns, subdomain

I have 2 domains, one at Register.com and one at Godaddy. I need them both to point to one Heroku app, and the following scenarios to work:

- http://domain1.com
- http://domain2.com
- http://www.domain1.com
- http://www.domain2.com
- https://domain1.com
- https://domain2.com
- https://www.domain1.com
- https://www.domain2.com

All of the above should all end up at one heroku app at https://www.domain1.com

Being that it's Heroku, I have no access to the .htaccess, and I've heard you're only allowed one SSL cert per app. I also have forwarding setup at GoDaddy, but apparently forwarding does not work if you try to forward from https on a non-hosted app.

Answer (score 0):

Your cert has to match the domain name that the client will try to answer, this means that when you make it the Subject Alternative Names (SANs) have to include www.domain1.com, domain1.com, www.domain2.com, domain2.com, and the domain/ip of your actual heroku app.

For your DNS records, if the heroku app is at a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN), and not an ip then follow these steps:

Forward your root domain, e.g. `example.com` to `www.example.com`, and make the CNAME record `www. 300 IN CNAME domain.of.heroku.app`

If the heroku app is reachable at a static ip follow this:
Make an the following A records for both your domains:

`@ 300 IN A ip-here`